# Determine the repartition of $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

How should i approach the following problem ?

Let $Y$ be a random variable  , $Y =\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^{n}X_k} $, where $(X_k)_{k=\overline{1-n}} \in U(0,1)$, are independent random variables.

I have absolutely no ideea how i should solve it? Hints / A solution would be really appreciated!

Comment: Use logarithms!

Comment: @kimchi lover Can you be more explicit please? I didn't really figured out what to do with logarithms. Thanks

Comment: The random variables $Z_k=-\log X_k$ have a well-known named probability distribution, as does the distribution of the sum of the $Z_k$. The distribution of your $Y$ is obtainable from this last.  But: I suspect you are asked for a limiting distribution for your $Y$.  That too can be found by sudying the distribution of the $Z_k$.  Are you comfortable with the weak law of large numbers? If so, that's applicable here.